# Attributes_table formatting using Arbre in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, arbre

I am displaying an ActiveAdmin registered model to the user.

```
ActiveAdmin.register ConfigurationFile do
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :filename
      row :content
    end
  end
end
```

`:content` is a string with newlines, but when rendered by Arbre newlines and extra whitespace are dropped.

How can I display `:content` without dropping extra whitespace and newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe):

```
 show do |configuration_file|
   attributes_table do
     # other rows
     row 'Content' do
       configuration_file.content.html_safe
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: This errors on the first line with `undefined method 'humanize' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: This worked in addition to adding `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the table's style.